# Thompson sampling with adaptive kernel density estimation

Tags: probability, bayesian, kernel-smoothing, maximum-entropy, multiarmed-bandit

This is an extension to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62872/multi-armed-bandit-for-general-reward-distribution), which is about handling arbitrary (potentially unbounded) reward distributions for the [multi-armed bandit problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit). Given a sequence of observed rewards $r_t \in \mathbb{R}$ for arm $i$, one could try to approximate the true reward distribution $R_i$ using a Gaussian posterior. It also occurred to me that one could use [adaptive kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_kernel_density_estimation) to approximate the true reward distribution. Has the application of adaptive KDE to Thompson sampling been studied? How does it compare empirically with the Gaussian approach, or other possible approaches?